# javascript sample with modification doesn't work

Tags: javascript

I got a "Making Layers that Move" javascript sample code and modified the functions that move left and right, creating the following code (I commented the modified lines, so you can see how it was):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>JavaScript Radio Example</title>
<script language=javascript type="text/javascript">

//var x=10;

function moveRight( )
{
        var layerElement = document.getElementById("layer2");
        //x+=10;
        //layerElement.style.left=x;
        layerElement.style.left += 10;
}

function moveLeft( )
{
        var layerElement = document.getElementById("layer2");
        //x-=10;
        //layerElement.style.left=x;
        layerElement.style.left -= 10;
}


</script>
</head>

<body>
<style type="text/css">

#layer1 {
background-color: yellow;
position: absolute;
height:90px;
width:90px;
left:0px;
top:100px;
}

#layer2 {
background-color: red;
position: absolute;
height:90px;
width:90px;
left:10px;
top:100px;
}

</style>

<p id="layer1">This is layer 1</p>
<p id="layer2">This is layer 2</p>

<form action="" name="orderForm">
<input type="BUTTON" value="Move Left" onClick="moveLeft()" />
<input type="BUTTON" value="Move Right" onClick="moveRight()" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, why isn't it working after the modification?

Comment: There ought to be an auto-flag that pops up when someone writes "doesn't work" without elaboration. Do you mean that there's an error? or the things don't move? or they move the wrong way? or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running this in a js debugger, e.g. Firebug. I get:

```
>>> var layerElement = document.getElementById("layer2")
>>> layerElement
<p id="layer2" style="left: 130px;">
>>> layerElement.style.left
"130px"
>>> layerElement.style.left -= 10
NaN
```

Notice that the value of layerElement.style.left is a string, "130px". No wonder when we try to subtract 10 from it, we get NaN.

The reason the old code works is that js apparently does some magic when you assign

```
layerElement.style.left = x
```

to convert x to a string with dimensional units.

Answer (score 1):

Node's style properties are strings! Basically you're concating two strings (second variable will be cated to first one's) => "100px"+10 = "100px10"
You have to cast this property to integer and than you can do the math.

```
var step = 10;
function moveRight(){
  var myNode = document.getElementById("layer2");
  myNode.style.left = parseInt(myNode.style.left)+step;
}
```